# Invoking a function in screen that succeeds the current one

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My app has a welcome screen, and when a user presses 'continue' the app then transitions to the setup screen.

The first thing the setup screen does upon mounting is make a fetch to grab some configurable options from the server.

As users sit for a few seconds on the welcome screen, it would make more sense to fire this fetch then so that the welcome screen is effectively 'pre-loaded' with the options.

One option would be to make the fetch on the welcome screen and pass the options via props. I don't really like this option though as the fetch isn't really to do with the welcome screen, it's for the setup screen.

Is it possible to 'pre-load' the setup screen, or perhaps fire a function from the welcome screen contained within the setup screen allowing me to make this fetch before the setup screen is mounted?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your user has to fill some kind of input, one the welcome screen is loaded you can fetch your data using for example `componentDidMount()` and store it in the welcome screen state using `this.setState({ data: yourData })` for example.

Then, one the user click on the 'continue' button, you just pass the data stored in `this.state.data` to the next screen. To do this, you will have to check how to do it depending on the navigation plugin you use.

For example with react-navigation:

```
onContinuePress = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', { data: this.state.data })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did state this option in my my question (see 'one option would be...') but I think you've reinstated my understanding that this is the only way to achieve what I am trying to do.